# Where is helicopter rotor attached on Allison Model 250 engine?

Tags: helicopter, turbine

Which section of the Allison Model 250 engine is attached to helicopter rotor?

Comment: None of it.  The gearbox is.

Comment: How is it connected to the gear box?

Comment: [By a shaft (or mast) to the gearbox output](http://www.tsb.gc.ca/eng/rapports-reports/aviation/2011/a11c0152/images/A11C0152-figure-1.png).

Comment: Thank You!!! Do you have Allison 250 maintenance manual and can upload by any chance?

Comment: Maintenance manuals are usually not public. why are you so interested in this specific model? does it have some peculiarity that other models don't have? how is it special?

Comment: I am in Jet Engine Shop at Aviation High School. My team was assigned to work this Allison 250 model. My instructor gave out job sheets pertaining with engine. We have to understand how this engine works in order to pass this class rotation.

Comment: If you took the engine out of the helicopter and  ran it, it would work exactly the same.  Why does the main rotor gearbox have  anything to do with the operation of the engine and why is your instructor not teaching you, or giving you reference to materials that you can learn from?

Comment: He wants us to research about it first over the weekend. He gives us textbooks but it does not have specific information pertaining to Allison 250.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. The engine is connected to a gearbox that transfers power to the rotor head. I don't know of any helicopter where the engine is directly connected to the rotor head. If it were, the helicopter would not be able to autorotate after an engine failure, unless the failure allowed the engine to continue to rotate.

Comment: Not to mention you'd have trouble trying to turn a rotor at 10,000 rpm, never mind whatever higher speed the turbine shaft actually turns at.  IIRC, motor rotors turn at something like 250+ rpm.  Gear reduction is a requirement.

Comment: That too, good points! *8)